# How do I index a vector using a string (C++)?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to index a vector using a string, like naming each element in a vector to use it's name instead of indexing it, just like in LUA.

for example in LUA you can:

```
list = {
   "John" = 3,
   "Sean" = 4,
   "James" = 1
}

print(list["James"])
```

The output would be equal to 1

I want a way to do this, but in C++.

I still haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start, but I expect a compact way to do this or another alternative that can help me fix my problem in C++.

Comment: `std::map<std::string, int>` seems what your are looking.

Comment: or `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` which has better time complexity.

Comment: or `list[ map_string_to_index_somehow("James") ]` in case you insist on array/vector

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it litearlly is asking on how to use a map and doesnt display any research effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `std::map`. Below example from [this site](https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/cpp/maps).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

int main() {
  // Initializing empty map
  std::map<std::string, int> emptyMap;

  // Initializing map with items
  std::map<std::string, int> clothingStore {{"tshirt", 10}, {"pants", 12}, {"sweaters", 18}};

  std::cout << clothingStore["sweaters"]; // Output: 18
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a map data structure for this problem rather than a vector. Maps are sets of key, value pairs. In this case you want a string key and integer value. [Here are the docs for using them in C++](https://cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Initializing map using map library
    // Each entry is a string key, integer value
    std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>> list {
        {"John", 3},
        {"Sean", 4},
        {"James", 1}
    };

    // Lookup 3 with "John" key, output to stdio
    std::cout << list["John"];
}
```

Comment: Missing `std::` in `string`.
Rather than `std::map<std::string, int>`, it's better to use `std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>>`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void#Notes